# Helio chart for canonical correlation

Tags: graphics, plotting

I'm trying to create a chart usually called "Helio chart". It's a chart type very suited for canonical correlation analysis involving several dependent and independent variables.

However, it is a little bit difficult to find good examples of for this chart on the web and the best example I have can be found on the 6th page of this paper on the NASA website:

http://ti.arc.nasa.gov/m/profile/adegani/Canonical%20Correlation.pdf

It is possible to create such a chart in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Starting from what input?

Comment: Here's a start for implementing this from scratch, using graphics primitives: `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Rotate[
    Translate[
     Scale[Rectangle[{-1, 0}, {1, 2}], .1 {1, l}, {0, 0}], {0, t}], 
    r, {0, 0}], {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}}, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> 3 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {r, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {{l, 1}, -5, 
  5}, {{t, 1}, 0.2, 2}]`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's some code that could help you to start:

sample data:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 30];
```

plot:

```
angleBar[max_, length_: .1][{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_, r1_}}, v_, meta_] :=
    Block[{angle, coords, x, y},
        angle = t0 + (t1 - t0)/2;
        coords = {Cos[angle], Sin[angle]};
        x = r0 coords;
        y = r1 coords;
        {{Gray, Dashed, Line[{x, y}]}, 
        {Black, If[meta[[1]] > 0, EdgeForm[],FaceForm[White]], 
          Translate[
            Rotate[Scale[
              Rectangle[{0, -.5}, {1, .5}], { meta[[1]]/max, length}, {0, 
          0}], angle, {0, 0}], x]} }
];

newdata = 1 -> # & /@ data;
max = Max[Abs[data]];
PieChart[newdata, ChartElementFunction -> angleBar[1.3 max, .1], 
   SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1.5}, 
   PolarGridLines -> {None, {0, 1.5}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

I added names and grouping.

```
angleBarName[max_, length_: .1][{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_, r1_}}, v_, meta_] :=
     Block[{angle, coords, x, y, tangle, offset},
         angle = t0 + (t1 - t0)/2;
         coords = {Cos[angle], Sin[angle]};
         x = r0 coords;
         y = r1 coords;
         If[Pi/2 <= Mod[angle, 2 Pi] <= 3/2 Pi, tangle = angle + Pi; 
            offset = {1, 0}, tangle = angle; offset = {-1, 0}];
         {{Gray, Dashed, Line[{x, 1.2 y}]}, {Black, 
          If[meta[[1, 1]] > 0, EdgeForm[], FaceForm[White]], 
          Translate[
            Rotate[Scale[
               Rectangle[{0, -.5}, {1, .5}], {meta[[1, 1]]/max, length}, {0, 
               0}], angle, {0, 0}], x]},
               Translate[
               Rotate[Text[Style[meta[[1, 2]], "Title", 10, Black], {0, 0}, 
               offset], tangle, {0, 0}], 2.1 x]}];

angleBarName[max_, length_: .1][{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_, r1_}},v_, {{"Group", msize_}}] :=
       Block[{angle, end, start, offset},
          If[v == msize, {},
           offset = (t1 - t0)/(v/msize *2);
           start = {Cos[t0 + offset], Sin[t0 + offset]};
           end = {Cos[t1 - offset], Sin[t1 - offset]};
           {Black, Thick, Line[{2.7 start, 3 start}], 
           Line[{2.7 end, 3 end}], 
           Circle[{0, 0}, 2.7, {t0 + offset, t1 - offset}]}]];

angleBarName[max_, length_: .1][{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_, r1_}}, v_, {"LineBreaker"}]:= {}
```

Sample data with names and grouping:

```
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 30], ChemicalData[][[;; 30]]}];
max = Max[Abs[data[[All, 1]]]];
getherdata = GatherBy[data, StringTake[#[[2]], 1] &];
gdata = Length[#] -> {"Group",1} & /@ getherdata;
newdata = 1 -> # & /@ Flatten[getherdata, 1];
```

Chart:

```
PieChart[{newdata, gdata}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> angleBarName[1.1 max, .1], 
  SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 1.5}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {None, {1.5}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I edited code to give space in the middle. To do that, I assumed the given data already separated into two part.

```
filterData[data_] :=
  Block[{fdata, size},
    fdata = Flatten[data, 1];
    size = 1/Length[fdata];
    {Join[{.005 -> "LineBreaker"}, 
           size -> # & /@ fdata, {.005 -> "LineBreaker"}], 
     Join[{.005 -> 
         "LineBreaker"}, (size Length[#]) -> {"Group", size} & /@ 
     data, {.005 -> "LineBreaker"}]}
]
```

sample data:

```
data = Transpose[{RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 22], ChemicalData[][[;; 22]]}];
ldata = GatherBy[data[[;; 7]], StringTake[#[[2]], 1] &];
rdata = GatherBy[data[[8 ;;]], StringTake[#[[2]], 1] &];
```

draw chart:

```
max = Max[Abs[ldata[[All, 1, 1]]], Abs[rdata[[All, 1, 1]]]];
newdata = MapThread[Join, {filterData[rdata], filterData[ldata]}];
PieChart[newdata, ChartElementFunction -> angleBarName[1.2 max, .1], 
   SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/2, "Clockwise"}, 1.5}, 
   PolarGridLines -> {None, {1.5}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   Epilog -> {Orange, Thick, Line[{{0, -4.5}, {0, 4.5}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, for convincing `PieChart` to do the work for you.

Comment: Well, this option is more similiar to the original Helio chart... however, it would be interesting to have the names plotted in the chart as well. It would be much more interesting to "divide" the names into categories, just like the original chart...

Comment: Another useful comment: there shouldn't be bars in the middle of the circle, because both circle parts should be splitted in the middle by a vertical thin line...

Comment: One more thing would be interesting to add: sometimes we have different numbers of dependent and independent variables... how could I change the chart to have, like, 7 variables on the left side and 15 variables on the right side?

Comment: Simply fantastic!!! Great job!

Comment: This is one of the most ineresting visualizations I've ever seen, and also implementation in Mathematica is superb.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a start:

```
out = Table[{i, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi - 2 Pi/20, 2 Pi/20}];
Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Directive[Black]], Disk[],
  {If[#[[2]] > 0, White, Black], 
     GeometricTransformation[ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {#[[2]] .5, .1}], 
                         {RotationMatrix[#[[1]]], {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#][[1]]}}]} & /@ out}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice.. I have made some tests with SectorChart, but it does not accept negative second arguments. +1

Comment: Didn't you make a prototype of a similar complicated radial chart on SO?

Comment: @rm-rf My programming abilities are as bad as my memory